# Error when in the edit view in rhe savechanges

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Edit view that edits the data from a Movie table, the view opens without error, but when I try to save the changes an error appear at db.SaveChanges();

this is what I have in the controller:

```
        public ActionResult Edit(int? Id)
        {

            if (Id == null)

                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            MoviesData movie = db.MoviesData.Find(Id);

            if (movie == null)

                return HttpNotFound();

            return View(movie);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "MovieID, MovieName, MovieCategory, MovieDescription, MovieYear")] MoviesData moviesData)
        {
                if(ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Entry(moviesData).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(moviesData);
```

And my view is the normal MVC Edit template:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>MoviesData</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })



------->@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MovieName)



        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MovieName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MovieName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MovieName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MovieDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MovieDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MovieDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MovieCategory, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MovieCategory, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MovieCategory, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MovieYear, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MovieYear, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MovieYear, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The `db.SaveChanges();` is outputting this error:

`System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.`

I have read what is in that link, but I didnt understand that well, what do I have to do? Also, do you need more information about my program?

Edit:

Movie Model:

```
public class MovieViewModel
    {
        public int MovieID { get; set; }
        public string MovieName { get; set; }
        public string MovieDescription { get; set; }
        public string MovieCategory { get; set; }
        public string MovieYear { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `moviesData.MovieID` when the exception is thrown? Why do you think that might be?

Comment: Please put a breakpoint on `if(ModelState.IsValid)`. Run to the breakpoint. Go to the `Immediate Window` and type in `?moviesData.MovieID`. What is displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view you are not located any input(EditorFor/Hiddenfor) for your `MovieId`, furthermore, when you post your form the value of `MovieId` is `0` in method of your controller so that you faced with error. For resolving this problem put below code snippet in your view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MovieId)
```

and I think it resolve your problem.